# Service/Server for PostreSQL keeps disconnecting (Windows 10)

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL at my home pc for testing - and the problem is that to start using it I need to run a command to start a server, like this:

pg_ctl -D "D:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data" start

then keep the CMD open and therefore I can use now the PostgreSQL - make connection to my databases.

After I close this CMD (and of course restart pc etc.) - then connection stops working.
Also I can start a service called - postgresql-x64-12 - PostgreSQL Server 12 - but the service keeps disabling after restart.

I wonder - is here some way to make it permanent and active even after restart (on windows)?? Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community. How did you install PostgreSQL?

Comment: You can remove the existing service (which is most likely using a non existing data directory) and register the service again with the correct data directory. This can be done using `pg_ctl unregister ...` and `pg_ctl register ...`